# How to implement interface having method returning Task (non-generic) in F#

Tags: c#, f#, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-to-f#

Say I have interface:

```
interface IProductRepository
{
    Task SaveProduct(Product p);
}
```

previously implemented by C# class:

```
class CSharpProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    public Task SaveProduct(Product p)
    {
        _db.Products.Add(p);
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement the same in F#:

```
type FSharpProductRepository =
    interface IProductRepository with
        member this.SaveProduct(p : Product) : Task = this.SaveProduct(p) // error 1

    member this.SaveProduct(p : Product) = async {
        db.Products.Add(p)
        return db.SaveChangesAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask // error 2
    }
```

But getting an error (1):

> This expression was expected to have type Task but here has type Async<'a>

and (2):

> Type constraint mismatch. The type Task is not compatible with type Task<'a>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `Task<'a>` is a subtype of `Task` you can do smth like this:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks

// stubs since I don't know what the actual code looks like
type Product = class end

type IProductRepository = 
    abstract SaveProduct: product: Product -> Task

type Db = 
    abstract Products: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Product>
    abstract SaveProductAsync: product: Product -> Task<int>

type Repository(db: Db) = 
    interface IProductRepository with
        member this.SaveProduct(p: Product) = 
            db.Products.Add(p)
            upcast db.SaveProductAsync(p)
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to start the `async` workflow with `Async.StartAsTask` but sadly that does not work here as this will need a generic task `Task<'a>` :( - so I think you have to use the `AwaitWaitHandle` method with the tasks `AsyncWaitHanlde`

```
type FSharpProductRepository =
    interface IProductRepository with
        member this.SaveProduct(p : Product) : Task = 
           this.SaveProduct(p)

    member this.SaveProduct(p : Product) = 
       async {
          db.Product.Add(p)
          let task = db.SaveChangesAsync() 
          let! _ = Async.AwaitWaitHandle (task :> IAsyncResult).AsyncWaitHandle
          return ()
       } |> Async.StartAsTask :> _
```

#### return the task directly:

It makes more sense to return the task directly, as in the code above (that just mirrors
the C# implementation) it just starts a thread, that starts another (`db.SaveChanges()`) waits for the changes to be saved and returns ... seems overkill to me.

This only would IMO only make sense if you would continue to work with the `async`-Workflow (remove the `Async.StartAsTask` - or if you would use the overload of `AwaitWaitHandle` that
will timeout after some milliseconds).

```
    member this.SaveProduct(p : Product) = 
      db.Product.Add(p)
      db.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Comment: @abatishchev yes - sorry it did not see that it returned `Async<bool>`

Comment: But how is it efficient comparing to the C# implementation? Terrible not?

Comment: wait I just saw that the `AwaitIAsyncResult` does not work - you need `AwaitWaitHandle` - I`ll change it ASAP

Comment: Better handling of a `Task` without a return type is a [planned change request for F#](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6092853-async-waittask-for-non-generic-task).

Comment: @abatishche efficient as in performant? well the question is why you want to put this into a `async` in the first place - you could just add  `p` and then just return the task `db.SaveChangesAsync()` returns - but the same is true for the C# version

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson yup - even better would be if the C# guys would get their types (`void` I look at you ) get into line ;) )

Comment: Yes, probably my actual C# code already returns the Task returned by SaveChangesAsync. I was writing from memory. Will it change the F# code?

Comment: You will still need to either `Wait` or `AwaitWaitHandle` at some point.

Comment: @Christopher: Can I ask to propose an update to Carsten's answer or post a new one?

Comment: @abatishchev with what? The proposed changes to F#? They might or might not come but will not work right now anyway

Comment: I mean how in F# to return from the method a task returned by SaveChangesAsync()?

Comment: at the random downvoter: a hint of what you don't like would be appreciated - it's not like we cannot talk about it ;)